# VU Meter only with 1LED (PWM) no IC except for OPAMP

Tags: operational-amplifier, diodes, sound

first of all yes it is homework but I worked on it and stuck at only this part. Maybe I am approaching on wrong side I am open to every advice.

I changed the idea in my mind.

I want to make a voltage selector circuit with opamps, capacitor, diodes only (Transisors and other IC's forbidden except only for opamp). But I couldn't find a way, do you have any advice for me ? Its like a dot display level meter (dot not bar) but I can not use LM3915 etc.

I have a varying DC voltage and want to make a circuit that choose a specific path for its amplitude. I don't need to save dc input I don't need its information, I only want to know its amplitude Voltage range

Like if dc source has 0-1V current flow goes path 1, if it has 1-2V current flow goes path2, if it has 2-3V current flow goes path3 etc. But when it goes from path 3, it cannot goes through path 1 and 2.

I know that I will use comparators but couldn't find a logical connection which will stop unneeded paths.

(Paths will not be open circuited as I show it on image there will be more connections to them by using buffers.)

I tried to make something I figured out this circuit. But I couldn't find a way to block lower levels. For example if I have 5 V as in figure, it doesn't go through R3 yes its achieved, but it shouldn't go through R1 as well it should only go through R2.

Thanks

[image: My Plan]

[image: What I tried]

Comment: Didn't you or someone in your class ask the same question a day or two ago? It seems to be gone now. As I commented on the previous question this will be difficult because of the discrete bands of sensitivity. It would be much simpler if the requirement is to make the PWM directly proportional to the sound level. Are you posting the question exactly as asked?

Comment: I don't understand the difference between yours and mine to be honest. I don't need to set specific thresholds.

I was simply thinking to dividing into output voltages of microphone. But as you say, PWM directly proportional to the sound level is somewhat what I need. Can you give more details ?,

Comment: If you have a requirement to give exactly 25% PWM at "very low sound" and 50% PWM in another signal strength band, etc., then you require a mix of analog and digital. If you can make the PWM directly proportional to volume level then you should be able solve it with a simple analog circuit. Do you need to edit your question to revise the specifications?

Comment: 1. Generate a voltage that matches desired on_%. 2. Produce a saw tooth waveform at desired on-off cycle time. 3. Feed 1 & 2 to a comparator - when sawtooth is < Vsignal output is low (say). When sawtooth is > Vsignal output is high. (or inverse if desired). You have PWM. 4. All the above can be achieved using opamps, or opamp & transistor mix or (if really keen) just transistors. Sawtooth is not too hard but exponential charge waveform of a capacitor may also be good enough. Using eg old el-cheapo LM324 gives 4 x single supply op-amps in one pkg. Note V_common-mode is < Vsupply.

Comment: I need exactly %25 PWM at veyr low and %50 at medium

Comment: Yes I know how to implement comparators with opamps. But I didn't understand how they discrete levels of microphone output ? Aren't they work as giving output of their Vcc or -Vcc so doesn't it mean that I lose my microphone information, and still I couldn't understand how it seperates.

Comment: I changed my question please help me.